# Transfer app from one itunesconnect account to another where it was deleted previously

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I had an app named **LightBeam** with bundle identifier as **com.lightcomp.LightBeam**, which was in **Ready For Sale status**.(But **not** being used anywhere)

My client wanted slight change in app name i.e. **LightBeam** to **LightBEAM** (case specific change).

Then I created an another build with product name as **LightBEAM** (with corresponding app id and distribution certificates and apns ssl)

To upload this new build, I deleted the complete app **LightBeam** from iTunes Connect account (was not knowing that it is not going to allow me to create another app with same name i.e LightBEAM).

**So, I lost that app name for that account even if it is different in letter cases.**

Now, There are few ways and questions in front me.

1) **As I can create app with same name in another account, Can I transfer that (LightBEAM - com.lightningcomp.LightBEAM) App from current account to previous account from where the app with LightBeam with BID com.lightcomp.LightBeam was deleted?**